# What is the purpose of (win) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
 $.modal({
        content: '<p>Are you sure you want to delete?</p>',
        title: 'Delete confimation',
        maxWidth: 500,
        buttons: {
                    'Yes': function(win) {
                        win.closeModal();
                    },
                    'No': function(win) {
                        win.closeModal();
                    }
        }
    });
```

Can someone explain what (win) means? I can see it used a few times but I am not sure what it is doing?

Comment: I assume win is the modal window object that has a closeModal() function defined on it. So you are passing the object to the function, which then calls the closeModal

Answer (score 3):

**Bottom-up explanation:**
It's a variable name to the anon function being passed as the value of key `Yes` and `No` in the object for `buttons`.

**Top-down explanation:** You are calling `modal` plugin and passing an argument to the function which is an object that has 4 members: `content`, `title`, `maxWidth`, `buttons`. `buttons` is an object (basically you are passing an object inside an object), with 2 members, `Yes` and `No`, which is are anonymous functions, each with an argument `win`.

Basically `win` is the instance of the modal you are opening via `$.modal()`

In this case, pressing both `Yes` and `No` will simply close the modal without doing anything